# Pandas aggregation on a group per row wise

Tags: pandas, apply, aggregation

I have a table like this

```
score
3
4
5
6
1
```

I want an HHI value corresponding to every row. e.g.

```
HHI(i) = sum of squares(x/sum(x)) where x!=score(i)
```

Can I do row-wise aggregation on remaining rows in pandas?